# Allocate physical memory buffer for ARM64 Linux Device Driver (without DMA support)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have to implement an ARM64 Linux driver for a device that needs to work with physical memory buffers and that doesn't support DMA (nor IOMMU).

My first attempt was to allocate the buffers with *kmalloc*, use the returned *vaddr* virtual address in the driver and send the *paddr* physical address obtained after a *virt_to_phys(vaddr)* translation to the device. I understand that (in general) this is not be the best approach, since the device might only know its bus-specific addresses. But my problem is that the *paddr* address returned by *virt_to_phys(vaddr)* isn't the same as the one listed in the PageTable for *vaddr*, so the device couldn't use it either (the *virt_to_phys* value looks like a shifted version of the real physical address).

What worked for me was using the DMA mapping API (e.g. *dma_alloc_coherent*), but I'm not sure if this is the best approach, since the device module doesn't support DMA.

Another option would be to pre-allocate a memory range (e.g. using a reserved-memory node in the device tree file) and *ioremap* it in the driver, but I'm not sure if that's OK either. Some of the buffers are only needed temporary (while the device is processing a command) and their size is variable (could get quite large). So, in this case, a dynamic allocation might be better.

Any idea what would be the best memory management approach (practice) for this case? Also, why would *virt_to_phys* called over a *kmalloc* address not return the correct physical address?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "device that needs to work with physical memory [...] that doesn't support DMA" - is self-contradictory: either the device can **a**ccess **m**emory, **d**irectly, or it can't. Why on earth would you send any kind of memory addresses to a device that couldn't make memory accesses? It sounds like your thing _is_ a DMA master, in which case the DMA mapping API is exactly the right tool for the job.

Comment: ...I suspect you may be getting mixed up with the concept of DMA controllers (the _dmaengine_ API in Linux), which are also DMA master devices, but ones which can be set up to go off and do PIO on _other_ devices that can't do their own DMA, and collect the data straight into memory for the CPU to pick up later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the confusion. Indeed, the device module can access the memory directly. I'm new to embedded development and my confusion was if it is a good practice to use this API when the device doesn't use an actual DMA controller (the reference manual saying that DMA is not implemented for my module). I did end up using the API eventually. It was the best way I could find to get linear/non-cacheable memory at runtime (without reserving it in the dts file). A limitation in my case is that I won't be able to use DMA scatter-gather for large buffers.

Comment: No need to apologise, I never meant to imply it _wasn't_ a horrible confusing mess of terminology ;) If you do need large buffers, then note that `dma_alloc_coherent` will also make use of CMA if available, so making sure that's enabled and bumping up CONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES if necessary might help make life a little easier.